# How to get a horizontal scroll view for Images in android?

Tags: android, gallery, horizontal-scrolling

I am planning to include the feature of horizontal scroll view which gets dynamically loaded for the images in the gallery.I have tried on IMAGE GALLERY but there are certain constraints in it.How to dynamically load the images by horizonatal scroll bar.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML: (design.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <FrameLayout android:layout_width="90px" android:layout_height="90px">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
  private RelativeLayout container;
  private int currentX;
  private int currentY;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.design);

    container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    int top = 0;
    int left = 0;

    ImageView image1 = ...
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);               
    container.addView(image1, layoutParams);

    ImageView image2 = ...
    left+= 100;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);               
    container.addView(image2, layoutParams);

    ImageView image3 = ...
    left= 0;
    top+= 100;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);               
    container.addView(image3, layoutParams);

    ImageView image4 = ...
    left+= 100;     
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);               
    container.addView(image4, layoutParams);
  }     

  @Override 
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            currentX = (int) event.getRawX();
            currentY = (int) event.getRawY();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
            int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();
            container.scrollBy(currentX - x2 , currentY - y2);
            currentX = x2;
            currentY = y2;
            break;
        }   
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            break;
        }
    }
      return true; 
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you ...