# How to scroll images horizontally in android like Flipkart app

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application, in my application i want to scroll images like Flipkart app, so please help me.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a horizontal scroll view for Images in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325020/how-to-get-a-horizontal-scroll-view-for-images-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use horizontal recycler view with custom row

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Recycler View as explained [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)
When setting the `LayoutManager` make sure to set the direction horizontal
like this

`LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(<your context>,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);`